# How to embed Nuxt app into another Nuxt app like widget?

Tags: nuxt.js

I need to insert one nuxt app into another.

The application as it connects must be completely isolated from the global one. It should be like a widget or component.

I considered creating modules but it should be a full application with routing, store, modules and other nuxt functionality.

It can be inserted using iFrame or something like that.

Thanks for the answers